# Gmail: set up filter to run when out of office

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is it possible in Gmail to set up a filter which only runs when the out of office/vacation responder is turned on?

The reason I want this is to be able to forward potentially important emails, but only when I'm not around to handle them myself.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail doesn't have a built-in feature to do that. Alternatives:

1. turn on/off manually the filter
2. use a third party app
3. build your own app

#### References

[Using filters - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en)
http://developers.google.com